# How to place interval between each div transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a moving `div` transition in such  way that it takes every step with an interval of one second. But when I put 5 consecutive steps together, the `div` simply moves from its initial position to its final position in one step without any interval. I tried to place a `setInterval` function to be called in each step after 1 second, but that didn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( function() {
    $('#executeButton').click(function() {
      test();
    });  
    function coords(dx, dy) {
      var cx = document.getElementById('block').style.marginLeft;
      var cy = document.getElementById('block').style.marginTop;
      cx = parseInt(cx) + 40 * dx;
      cy = parseInt(cy) + 40 * dy;
      if (cx < 0) cx = 0;
      if (cy < 0) cy = 0;
      if (cx > 360) cx = 360;
      if (cy > 360) cy = 360;
      document.getElementById('block').style.marginLeft = cx + 'px';
      document.getElementById('block').style.marginTop = cy + 'px';
    }

    function test(){
      move('4');
      move('4');
      move('4');
      move('2');
      move('2');
    }

    function move(id) {
      if (id == '1') {
        coords('0','-1');
      } else if (id == '2') {
        coords('0','1');
      } else if (id == '3') {
        coords('-1','0');
      } else if (id == '4') {
        coords('1','0');
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#game {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 39px, #888 39px, transparent 40px), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 39px, #888 39px, transparent 40px);
  background-size: 40px 40px, 40px 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}


#block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: red;
  outline: 1px solid;
}

#character {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="movefunction.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="movecharacter.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="executeButton">Execute</button>
    <div id="panel">
      <div id="game">
        <div id="block" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 40px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve the code indentation. You can do this easily while editing the code snippet: select the code and press Shift+Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to define the start delay of your moves.

```
function test(){
    move(4);                   // instant start
    setTimeout(move, 2000, 4); // + 1s transition + 1s delay
    setTimeout(move, 4000, 4); // + 1s transition + 1s delay
    setTimeout(move, 6000, 2); // + 1s transition + 1s delay
    setTimeout(move, 8000, 2); // + 1s transition + 1s delay
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( function() {
 $('#executeButton').click(function() {
        test();
    });  
   function coords(dx, dy) {
     var cx = document.getElementById('block').style.marginLeft;
     var cy = document.getElementById('block').style.marginTop;
     cx = parseInt(cx) + 40 * dx;
     cy = parseInt(cy) + 40 * dy;
     if (cx < 0) cx = 0;
     if (cy < 0) cy = 0;
     if (cx > 360) cx = 360;
     if (cy > 360) cy = 360;
     document.getElementById('block').style.marginLeft = cx + 'px';
     document.getElementById('block').style.marginTop = cy + 'px';
    }

    function test(){
        move(4);
        setTimeout(move, 2000, 4);
        setTimeout(move, 4000, 4);
        setTimeout(move, 6000, 2);
        setTimeout(move, 8000, 2);
   }

   function move(id) {
      if (id == '1') {
        coords('0','-1');
      } else if (id == '2') {
        coords('0','1');
      } else if (id == '3') {
        coords('-1','0');
      } else if (id == '4') {
        coords('1','0');
      }
   }
    
  });
});
```

```css
#panel {
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#game {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 39px, #888 39px, transparent 40px), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 39px, #888 39px, transparent 40px);
   background-size: 40px 40px, 40px 40px;
   border-style: solid;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
}


#block {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
   transition: 1s;
   background-color: red;
 outline: 1px solid;
}

#character {
 width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    outline: 1px solid;
    float: left;
 background-color: red;
   transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="movefunction.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="movecharacter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="executeButton">Execute</button>
<div id="panel">
<div id="game">
 <div id="block" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 40px;">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @eisbehr, I don't know how to send message in stackoverflow, but can you please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39119523/how-to-check-if-one-div-overlapped-another-during-transition-from-one-position-t/

Comment: I clicked on upvote, it said I do not have enough reputation to do the same. And how to mark the answer as successfully answered?