# How to check if one div overlapped another during transition from one position to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( function() {
 $('#executeButton').click(function() {
        test();
    });  
   function coords(dx, dy) {
     var cx = document.getElementById('block').style.marginLeft;
     var cy = document.getElementById('block').style.marginTop;
     cx = parseInt(cx) + 40 * dx;
     cy = parseInt(cy) + 40 * dy;
     if (cx < 0) cx = 0;
     if (cy < 0) cy = 0;
     if (cx > 360) cx = 360;
     if (cy > 360) cy = 360;
     document.getElementById('block').style.marginLeft = cx + 'px';
     document.getElementById('block').style.marginTop = cy + 'px';
    }

    function test(){
        move(4);
        setTimeout(move, 2000, 4);
        placePostion();
        setTimeout(move, 4000, 4);
        placePostion();  
        setTimeout(move, 6000, 2);
        placePostion();
        setTimeout(move, 8000, 2);
        placePostion();
   }

   function move(id) {
      if (id == '1') {
        coords('0','-1');
      } else if (id == '2') {
        coords('0','1');
      } else if (id == '3') {
        coords('-1','0');
      } else if (id == '4') {
        coords('1','0');
      }
   }
    
   function placePostion() {
      var block = $('#block').position();
      var dest = $('#dest').position();
      if (block.top == dest.top && block.left == dest.left) {
          alert("reached");
      }
   } 
    
  });
});
```

```css
#panel {
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#game {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 39px, #888 39px, transparent 40px), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 39px, #888 39px, transparent 40px);
   background-size: 40px 40px, 40px 40px;
   border-style: solid;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 10px;
}


#block {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
   transition: 1s;
   background-color: red;
 outline: 1px solid;
}

#dest {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
    outline: 1px solid;
}

#character {
 width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    outline: 1px solid;
    float: left;
 background-color: red;
   transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="movefunction.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="movecharacter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="executeButton">Execute</button>
<div id="panel">
<div id="game">
 <div id="block" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 40px;">
 </div>
    <div id="dest" style="margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 120px;">
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added the snippet. Here when the red block reaches the blue block, it should say the alert whereas currently its behaving like they are having the same position from the start itself. It should actually move and when it reaches the blue block then only it should say reached. For different final position it should not display anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to put `placePostion` inside the `setTimeout` too, otherwise it will be executed directly and not get the correct positions.
2. You need to use `offset` instead of `position`.
3. Because your `block` is floated you need to add the height to the offset `top` too.

```js
$(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#executeButton').click(function() {
      test();
    });

    function coords(dx, dy) {
      var cx = document.getElementById('block').style.marginLeft;
      var cy = document.getElementById('block').style.marginTop;
      cx = parseInt(cx) + 40 * dx;
      cy = parseInt(cy) + 40 * dy;
      if (cx < 0) cx = 0;
      if (cy < 0) cy = 0;
      if (cx > 360) cx = 360;
      if (cy > 360) cy = 360;
      document.getElementById('block').style.marginLeft = cx + 'px';
      document.getElementById('block').style.marginTop = cy + 'px';
    }

    function test() {
      move(4);
      placePostion();

      setTimeout(function() {
        move(4);
        placePostion();
      }, 2000);
      
      setTimeout(function() {
        move(4);
        placePostion();
      }, 4000);

      setTimeout(function() {
        move(2);
        placePostion();
      }, 6000);

      setTimeout(function() {
        move(2);
        placePostion();
      }, 8000);

    }

    function move(id) {
      if (id == '1') {
        coords('0', '-1');
      } else if (id == '2') {
        coords('0', '1');
      } else if (id == '3') {
        coords('-1', '0');
      } else if (id == '4') {
        coords('1', '0');
      }
    }

    function placePostion() {
      var block = $('#block').offset();
      var dest = $('#dest').offset();
      
      if (block.top + $('#block').height() == dest.top && block.left == dest.left) {
        alert("reached");
      }
    }

  });
});
```

```css
#panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-style: solid;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
#game {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 39px, #888 39px, transparent 40px), linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 39px, #888 39px, transparent 40px);
  background-size: 40px 40px, 40px 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
#block {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: red;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
#dest {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
#character {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  outline: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="executeButton">Execute</button>
<div id="panel">
  <div id="game">
    <div id="block" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 40px;"></div>
    <div id="dest" style="margin-left: 160px; margin-top: 120px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks , I will try.

Comment: When I was trying this code, the moment red box reached the blue box, block.top + $('#block').height() value was different from dest.top, still for the operator == it came as true, can you please explain that.

Comment: Also in the function test() if I will place the order as move(2), move(2), move(4),move(4),move(4), it reaches the destination but fails to alert reached.

Comment: Well, I was aware that this could happen. The problem seems to be the design of your game field. You use things like `float` and `margin` to create the board. This is not the best idea it you would like to work with positions. This could happen to you on many kinds. I would suggest to redesign your game, working with absolute positions. This would save you many troubles imo. @suchit

Comment: As you said, I removed float and margin, placed top and left along woth absolute. And also made the corresponding changes in the javascript page. But then even the movement doesn't happen.

Comment: Create a fiddle with your new code. How should I help you without? @suchit

Comment: Sorry for late reply, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/streetyhunk/b6jp5mg0/

Comment: I thought of using jquery-ui drag and drop function, so as if the red box reaches the blue box, the droppable's drop property gets activate. But that   seem to work only during drag event. Here is the fiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/streetyhunk/hok9rnu8/1/

Comment: I changed your code how *I* would do it! I comment many things and improved your code here and there. I hope it will guide you to the right direction. See a fully working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/b6jp5mg0/2/ @suchit